# Extract data from JSON format using python

Tags: python, json, format, extract

```
df= [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'},
 {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'},
 {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
```

How could I extract data from this format?

The output should look like this:

```
id    Name
16    Animation
35    Comedy
10751 Family
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is the actual problem here, but are you looking for something like this?

```
data = [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'},
     {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'},
     {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
    
print("Id  Name")
    
for i in data:
    print(i['id'], i['name'])
```

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot